# CatalogCardLayout (Carousel Images) for Gmail Annotation

Tags: json, annotations, catalog, card, gmail-promo-tab

We have successfully implemented Gmail Annotations for our emails. However, with Black Friday around the corner, we wanted to utilize multiple images with Catalog Cards. I found the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/reference) that calls out the Item Properties and such, but I have no idea how to code this into JSON-LD. I use 250ok/Validity's script as a base, which is below. Can someone help me code or provide sample code for the Catalog Card annotation?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "logo": "http://250ok.com/img/favicon-black.png"
},{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "subjectLine": "Time to renew your 250ok Account"
},{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "DiscountOffer",
    "description": "10% off",
    "discountCode": "RENEW2019",
    "availabilityStarts": "2020-11-06T08:00:00-07:00",
    "availabilityEnds": "2020-11-25T08:00:00-07:00"
},{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "PromotionCard",
    "image": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/250ok-wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/03212604/promo_sample.png"
}]
</script>
```

[Example Image of the Catalog Card Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcjSR.png)

Comment: Hi there @MathewAdkins! I've reviewed your scenario. Just to add some light on this matter I want to ask you if you [tested the schema](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/testing-your-schema#schema_validator).

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Thanks for replying! The code from my original post does work for regular Gmail Annotations, however, I am trying to do the card carousel. I have tried various testing sites and I can't seem to get anything to work. I don't have JSON-LD experience, so I have been winging it.

Comment: While Gmail has posted the code for catalog cards, I don't think they render in the Gmail app yet. I'm keeping a close eye on it and will update this question once I see them live.

Comment: @BrianSisolak-PeakInbox any advancement on this since 2020?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the catalog cards working in the latest version of Gmail on Android when using a Gmail account that ends in `promotabtesting@gmail.com`. I have not seen this work on an iOS device yet nor on non-testing Gmail accounts (https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/best-practices#testing)