# How do you use carousel/multiple images in the gmail promotion annotations?

Tags: gmail-promo-tab

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792320/catalogcardlayout-carousel-images-for-gmail-annotation) about using multiple images in the gmail annotations but never found any documentation on how to accomplish it. I was hoping the google team in charge of this feature could shed some light on how to code this in JSON-LD and point me to documentation on it if it exists!

[example screenshot of a promo email that shows multiple images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ude3s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is called Product Carousel annotation. More here https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview#product-carousel