# Where to find documentation about carousel/multiple images in the gmail promotion annotations?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-promo-tab

Duplicate of [How do you use carousel/multiple images in the gmail promotion annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73708512/how-do-you-use-carousel-multiple-images-in-the-gmail-promotion-annotations) but has the question is simply associated with the gmail-promo-tabs tag and not the gmail-api asked by the official Gmail API support I thought it's maybe not visible.

The problem is the same, I saw examples of multiples images carousel in Gmail including [CatalogCardLayout (Carousel Images) for Gmail Annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64792320/catalogcardlayout-carousel-images-for-gmail-annotation) but I don't found any documentation about it.

I want to know if this functionality still exist and where is the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

They just updated the documentation with the details here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview#product-carousel